# How to access multiple values from a function while only calling the function one time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looping through documents looking for occurrences of words contained in a corpus list.  I noticed that every time I use a value returned from the function, it calls the whole function again.

```
def function1():
    print ("function1")
    x = 1
    y = 2
    return (x,y)

print (function1()[0])
print (function1()[1])
```

I'm getting as a result...

```
function1
1
function1
2
```

which indicates that the function ran 2 times.  Is there a way to just have the function run one time?

So hopefully the output would look like...

```
function1
1
2
```

The code is taking hours to run, and I think this is part of the reason why.  Edit:  I realize I could assign the output tuple to a variable, but am trying to avoid global variables.

Comment: `x, y = function1(); print(x); print(y)`?

Comment: you're not returning multiple values you're returning a _tuple_

Comment: In my actual code, I'm returning a tuple with 10 values, and each time I refer to one of those values, the function runs again.  It seems unnecessary since the data input (and the tuple output) isn't changing.  I'm trying to understand how to not have the function run multiple times when it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Assign the return value of the function to a variable.
Then access the variable as many times as you need to -- the function need not be called again (unless it is a function which will give you a different return value when called again -- such as getting the current time.  But you wouldn't be asking the question if you were doing something like that.)

Comment: Is this equivalent to using a global variable though?

Comment: It is global if it is in the main.  But generally in a program most of the code is organized into functions and classes -- in that case the variable would be a local, class, or instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

Assign function1 result to a variable.

This is the example:

```
Example = function1()
print(Example[0])
print(Example[1])
```

It will only run the function once and you can access the data that returned by that function as many times as you like without running the function again.